# Touchpad doesn't work after certain time

Tags: touchpad, hp

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and now I have a disturbing problem.
After the booting everything works fine. But after a certain time, the touchpad does not work anymore. Only a restart is helping. Its quite annoying -.-

A USB Mouse is always working, its only the touchpad.

I have added the following code to be executed after start: `syndaemon -i 1 -K -d`because the "Disable touch while typing" option is not in the settings.

My Laptop is a HP355 (Ubuntu 16.04LTS).

Output of `xinput`:

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Receiver                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Receiver                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4G Receiver                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Output of `xinput list-props 15`:

`Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (275): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (276):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (277):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (278):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (299):  1534, 5402, 1259, 4613
    Synaptics Finger (300): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (301):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (302):   261
    Synaptics Tap Durations (303):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (304):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (305):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (306):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (307):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (308): 119, 119
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (309): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (310):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (311): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.033608, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (312):    1
    Synaptics Locked Drags (313):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (314):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (315): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (316):   1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (317): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (318):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (319): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (320):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (321): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (322):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (323): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (324):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (325): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (326):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (327):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (328):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (329):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (330): 80, 46
    Synaptics Area (331):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (332): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (264):    2, 7
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event12"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Please add output of `xinput list-props 15`.

Comment: See the update in the answer.

Comment: Now.. sry, i have not noticed that i added the wrong device

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Mouse and disable the option "disable while typing". It should be there.

Comment: No it is not. There are three options: "Tap to click", "Two finger scroll" and "Natural scrolling".

Comment: This is very wierd. I suggest installing `libinput`. It has a much better palm detection functionality.

Comment: I have installed `libinput`. I have added the line "Disable while typing" in its configs. I have also removed the line `syndaemon -i 1 -K -d` from the starting programs. The touchpad is still disabled while typing. I hope it will work now. Thank you so far :)

Comment: Where did you add "Disable while typing"? Libinput has it by default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you added `syndaemon -i 1 -K -d`.

If at the same time the option "Disable touchpad while typing" is enabled, two instances of syndaemon are running. This finally lead to touchpad freeze.

Disable that option or remove the syndaemon command.

Comment: I added this line because there is no option "Disable touchpad while typing" in the Mous & Touchpad settings. My Ubuntu version is 16.04LTS

Comment: Is is a standard Ubuntu with unity?

Comment: Yes, standard Ubuntu with unity.

Comment: OK. Post the output then, let's see what is the problem.

Comment: Which output? Can you tell me how?

Comment: See the comment under your question.